# I Used dd to Backup All My Files, now It (Kali Linux) Won't Boot

Tags: boot, kali-linux, dd

I used this command to copy my files into an external hdd

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb/Backup.img
```

Now my laptop wont boot, it just shows Boot menu and Application Menu.
I deleted the .img file because I couldn't extract it.

This is how it looks after I turn on my laptop
[image]
when I pressed enter, It goes back to this screen

If I choose the Application Menu and select Diagnostic Splash Screen (it's the only option), it shows this
[image]

Do you have any solution(s) for this?
Thanks.

Comment: What .img file? That backup command didn't create any .img file.

Comment: how is the laptop showing menus if it does not boot?

Comment: ah sorry, I forgot something, I've fixed the command @John

Comment: Was `/dev/sdb` a directory from the start or did you remove the `sdb` device file and create a directory in its place?

Comment: I plugged in my device at that time, so it is a directory from the start

Comment: @jsotola I've attached an image

Comment: I would be surprised if any Linux automatically created `/dev/sdb` *as a directory*.

Comment: Pls help, I got important files in there

Comment: Then boot under some honest rescuecd-like usb stick, and consider what you can do with your block devices.

Comment: @QuinRa I'm sorry, but a system running Kali is arguably *not intended* as a secure storage for your files. By now, it's probably easiest to restore from a backup.

Comment: The corrected `dd` command, if that is what you used, did not do what you think it did. Given the comments I've seen here and the evidence in your images, you have more than likely irrevocably lost all data on this machine (barring use of a potentially very expensive data rescue service). Today's lesson: don't use `dd` as a backup program. It is not, never has been, and was never intended as a backup program.

Comment: And just so the op knows, it  was not named after the Hindu God. Please, use another distro.

Comment: Did you read the Kali FAQ? - https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/

Answer (score 2):

Your command would have failed - even with `sudo` - much like this

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb/Backup.img
dd: failed to open '/dev/sdb/Backup.img': Not a directory
```

There are three possibilities:

1. The command you have shown us doesn't match what you actually typed
2. You removed the block device `/dev/sdb` and recreated it as a directory. In this case you would have filled up the RAM-based `/dev` filesystem seconds after starting the copy, and no other change would have been made
3. You somehow managed to mount the external disk on `/dev/sdb`, in which case the Backup.img file will be safely on that external disk

Neither of the second or third options will have caused damage to your source disk `/dev/sda`, so the failure to boot is caused by a command you haven't shown and unrelated to the issue *as described to us*.

By the way, copying a live disk image like this is a good way to get a silently corrupted backup. At best, the backup will fail immediately. Do not use this method for backing up a live system. And don't use `dd` ever, until you understand why I'm saying this.

Answer (score -4):

To copy disk to disk use `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb`

To copy to an image file you have to mount the filesystem first:

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt

dd if=/dev/sda of=/mnt/sda.img
```

As for why you cannot boot anymore maybe part of your bootloader were on sdb?

Try a live image und check for your data on sda:

```
fdisk -l /dev/sda
```

Are there any partitions? If not try testdisk /dev/sda

Can you mount the filesystems

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt

ls -l /mnt

umount /mnt
```

for sda1, 2, 3 ...

Good luck

Comment: No no no no no!

Comment: @roaima What will happen if I do this? Is it ok if I use a rescue disk/live image? To save my important files first?

Comment: @QuinRa from a Rescue disk, you could mount the disk directly. Or if you want to take an image of `/dev/sda` and put it on a filesystem mounted on `/mnt/other_disk`, use something like `cat /dev/sda >/mnt/other_disk/disk.img`. Just be careful because from a Rescue disk you may find that `sda` isn't what you think it is. Be _very_ careful

Comment: @roaima So, I can use a rescue disk without damaging the files that are still in the device right? Thanks^^